# Exported object from blender doesnt work properly in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, object, three.js, blender

I try to import blender object to my javascript code. But the object doesn't render like in blender. I export as .obj from blender.

Here is my blender:

[image: blender screenshot]

exporting options on left and on the right is how it look in threeJS:

[image: three.js output]

Comment: @Osaco Protal , thank you for the edit.

Comment: Another way would be to check the "triangulate faces" box. Sometimes Blender exports Face4 types instead of Face3, that can cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple tutorial for [Three.js and Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d41Fw_CIxHA).

As the easiest way to do this is to use the `Three.ColladaLoader`. Place your `.dae` files in a folder titled `models` in your `/root` directory.
Call the `Collada` function from within the `init()` function.

```
function init(){
    scene = new THREE.scene;
    ...
    var object1 = new PinaCollada('model1', 1);
    scene.add(object1); 
    var object2 = new PinaCollada('model2', 2);
    scene.add(object2); 
    ...
}

function Collada(modelname, scale) {
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    var localObject;
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( 'models/'+modelname+'.dae', function colladaReady( collada ) {
        localObject = collada.scene;
        localObject.scale.x = localObject.scale.y = localObject.scale.z = scale;
        localObject.updateMatrix();
    });
    return localObject;
}
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644573/7707749) answer or [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26923/how-do-i-export-a-simple-blender-3d-model-without-armature-to-three-js) one.
Maybe it brings you ideas and maybe not, hope it helps!

Comment: oww thank you very much, colladaLoader worked for me.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help!